# I just want to add a <label> to the checkout page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I just want to add a label that says "*Residential Addresses May Incur Additional Charges" somewhere in the shipping methods portion of onepage checkout.

I can't find where any of it is stored, my only clue is getChildHtml('additional'), which seems to be where it's all generated from.

I need to add this until I can figure out how to put a residential checkbox on the address page for fedex/ups quotes.

Anyone have any idea, because this should really be simple, but it's incredibly complicated

I mean I'm thinking of just making a jQuery block that'll append the label somewhere on pageload since I can't seem to find where this html is stored :/

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out, even though it's not ideal...

in the shipping_method.phtml file, you need to find this line of code:`<div id="onepage-checkout-shipping-method-additional-load">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('additional') ?>
    </div>`

Then you can insert a  or whatever before it and it will show up beneath everything.

Why must they make this so hard...